# javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: org.omnifaces.component.output.ConditionalComment not found

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I have upgraded from JSF 2.2.7 to 2.2.15 and I am now receiving the following error when running Jetty:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object:
>   org.omnifaces.component.output.ConditionalComment not found.